# localised google map not rendering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm struggling to see why the Google Map isn't automatically rendering to the users location.

Working test URL http://showcaseimagery.com/testing/skel/eton/home.php

The default view, when mousing over the main panel is currently showing like this...

[image]

Instead of either rendering the default US locality or rendering the users current location like this...
[image]

When I get the map loaded (manually via the dropdown or the zipcode areas) I am finding that the rendered map is incomplete.
As you can see in this 2nd image, the bottom section of the map and the map controls aren't completely loaded.

To summarise:

- I don't know why the map isn't loading correctly.
- The rendered map is incomplete.

Thanks for your thoughts and comments on the matter.

Comment: You only create  the map when getCurrentPosition was successfull, there is no fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely because you instantiate the map while the div is not visible. Try forcing a resize like this:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()); // trigger a property change
```

When your map is first actually displayed.

**EDIT**

Actually the problem is because of the CSS animations you have added and specifically this one:

```
.overlay-slide-in-up:hover img {
    transform: translateY(-80%);
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

Line 308 of app.css. This essentially makes all the images inside the google maps div to be moved 80% upwards. In order to avoid this, add the following CSS **after** the above declaration:

```
#mapArea img {
  transform: none;
}
```

This will then allow all the images inside the map div be excluded from the particular animation.

Comment: thanks @kagelos, sounds like a good idea. and i'd put this where in the sites js file....top or bottom?

Comment: Hey @kagelos, that's great thanks. That has definitely fixed the second issue I was having (The rendered map is incomplete).

I would have never thought to look in the css file for a resolve. Can I ask **how** you determined this....so I know for future use ;)

Comment: Actually @kagelos ref the other issue. I've noticed that even this simple *current location* test [http://showcaseimagery.com/testing/geo-location/current-position/](http://showcaseimagery.com/testing/geo-location/current-position/) isn't even working.

Therefore I assume the method has changed :/

Comment: @ShowcaseImagery I found the issue by trial and error. At first I realized that the fact that the div is initially not visible, was not a problem, since it had non zero dimensions. Therefore I started removing the css classes of the parent elements until I found which one caused the issue.

Now about the current location that you say it's not working, it is working in Firefox. Chrome however recently changed and doesn't allow pages that don't come from a secure site (HTTPS) to access it. Are you testing this with Chrome? Finally if the answer above answers your question, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful response @kagelos (which I can't **@**) for some reason. Yes, I can see your method now, thanks for the help on that point.
I've researched the secure site issue you mentioned and confirmed this in the dev console too. Any suggestion to the area I should be looking to update? ie, api console, javascript code, html code?

Comment: Just run it from a secure site. You van do this even with a self signed certificate. In the final production site you will jave to buy a proper certificate.

Comment: yeah i use an ssl, though i was referencing http in the js. duh. Thanks a ton Kagelos